# MSBuild ignores GatherAllFilesToPublish?

Tags: msbuild

So, I created a publish profile for my web app. I did this with the GUI in VS 2017 Enterprise. I then found an example of how to change the pubxml to make it zip all the output files. Eventually I ended up with this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
        <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
        <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
        <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
        <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
        <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
        <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
        <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
        <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
        <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
        <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
        <publishUrl>bin\Release\Publish</publishUrl>
        <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
        <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="ZipPublishOutput" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish">
        <Exec Command='powershell -nologo -noprofile -command "compress-archive -force -path $(WPPAllFilesInSingleFolder)\* -destinationpath $(publishUrl).zip"' />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

This works perfectly fine if I do a publish through Visual Studio. However, I've been trying everything I can think of to get this to work in MSBuild, with no luck.

Here is an example of what I think should work:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" WebApp.csproj /nologo /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=ReleasePublish

And for reference, here is the version of MSBuild:

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.9.20+g88f5fadfbe for .NET Framework

I know MSBuild is finding the profile pubxml because I can make a change to the settings, such as publishUrl, and those changes are applied the next time I run MSBuild. What doesn't seem to work is the ZipPublishOutput target. And even running MSBuild with diagnostic verbosity shows that GatherAllFilesToPublish never runs, which would mean my target wouldn't run.

I've found many different suggestions and nothing seems to help. A lot of the solutions I found seemed to be with MSBuild not finding the pubxml, but that's not the case here.

So, is GatherAllFilesToPublish something that is Visual Studio specific, and therefore MSBuild doesn't know about it? That seems like how it's acting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the same problem using msbuild with Jenkins.
To execute the target *GatherAllFilesToPublish* with msbuild I had to add the target */t:GatherAllFilesToPublish* in the msbuild command line.

You should have something like this :

> /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=fullPathToMyPubXML.pubxml
>   /t:GatherAllFilesToPublish

Comment: That does seem to work. I guess I was expecting it to be implied as part of the publish profile, but I guess that's not how it works. Thanks.

Comment: It should work by default, but it seems that MsBuild and Visual Studio don't use the same rules, or simply it's just broken in MsBuild. So we have to rely on cheap trick to make it work unfortunately.

I guess it's related to the target GatherAllFilesToPublish being defined in Microsoft.WebApplication.targets.

Comment: Well, I guess I spoke too soon. The zip file that I get from running that publish profile through VS is about 10 megs larger and works, whereas this one generates something that doesn't work.

Comment: By default, MSBuild use the debug configuration to publish.
Use the release configuration by adding :

/p:Configuration=Release

Comment: I was. This is what I ran: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" WebApp.csproj /nologo /verbosity:minimal /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=ReleasePublish /t:GatherAllFilesToPublish

Comment: What's interesting is that the bin folder that gets put into the zip file contains dlls for only some of the projects in my solution, but not all of them, which is why it's not working. I had at least one missing dll when I deployed. And I don't think there's anything special about the projects it's excluding.

Comment: Oh, I think I see. The missing project isn't added as a reference in the WebApp project, but instead is a reference in another project that is referenced to WebApp. Apparently VS must know how to handle this situation and MSBuild does not.