# In Visual Studio 2022 is it possible add a post build task that creates a zip file?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2022

Ive tried the following with no sucess...content of pubxml where i have added 2 additional targets for post publish.

```
  <Target Name="CustomActionsBeforePublish" BeforeTargets="BeforePublish">
        <Message Text="Actions BeforePublish" Importance="high" />
        <Exec  Command="echo HEllo Ruban" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="CustomActionsAfterPublish" AfterTargets="AfterPublish">
        <Message Text="Actions AfterPublish" Importance="high" />
        <Exec  Command="echo HEllo" />
    </Target>
 -->
 <Target Name="ZipPublishOutput" AfterTargets="GatherAllFilesToPublish">
 <Exec Command= 'echo Hello'/>
    <Exec Command='powershell -nologo -noprofile -command "compress-archive -force -path $(WPPAllFilesInSingleFolder)\* -destinationpath $(publishUrl).zip"' />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="ZipPublishOutput" AfterTargets="FileSystemPublish">
  <Exec Command= 'echo Hello'/>
    <ZipDirectory SourceDirectory="$(PublishDir)" DestinationFile="$(PublishDir)\..\Test.zip" />
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(PublishDir)" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use a publish profile to the file system along with msbuild and powershell to accomplish this.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>C:\myreleasefolder</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>False</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

msbuild and powershell commands:

```
msbuild website.publishproj /m /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=ProdPrep
powershell.exe -nologo -noprofile -command "& { Add-Type -A 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'; [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::CreateFromDirectory('.', '../myzipfoldername.zip'); }"
```

Adjust CreateFromDirectory arguments as required for the location defined in your publish profile. You may be able to use this powershell command in your Exec command, not sure if that's the piece you're having trouble with.

This is using VS2017 but may help: [MSBuild ignores GatherAllFilesToPublish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53423119/msbuild-ignores-gatherallfilestopublish)
The poster uses the same powershell command as it looks like you're using.